# Botón "volver" a la ventana principal dependiendo del tipo de perfil del usuario

Tags: php, botón, seguridad, sesiones, users-roles

Necesito un botón  que **dependiendo del tipo de perfil** de un usuario me permita volver a una pagina principal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este botón puede estar en cualquier página secundaria del sistema pero lo probé en el archivo registrar_venta.php de la carpeta modulo_venta(el sistema tiene varios modulos  y en todos debe aplicarse el mismo botón).

Por cada tipo de perfil que existe hay una interfaz y Hay ventanas/páginas del sistema que son compartidas entre perfiles, es decir dos tipos de perfiles pueden acceder a la misma ventana. Por eso no puedo hacer algo como esto

```
 <a href="interfaz1.php" >  Volver</a>
```

Ya que si la persona con el tipo de perfil 2  cliquea el botón "volver" entrará a una la interfaz1 en vez de la interfaz2 que es la correspondiente.

Mostraré a continuación como hago el código de validación en el **LOGIN** del sistema, el archivo se llama **validar_login.php y esta en la carpeta ingreso(una carpeta diferente de la carpeta del archivo registrar_venta.php**

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Esta debe ser siempre la primera instrucción
    include ("../includes/conexion.php");

    // Limpiar variables de sesión
    $_SESSION["user"] = '';
    $_SESSION["rol"] = 0;

    //funcion de seguridad
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["documento"]) ;
    //funcon md5 contraseña encriptada
    $clave = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["clave"]) ;
    // También se debe escapar este dato
    $rol = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["rol"]);

    
    $consulta = " SELECT * FROM tblusuario WHERE documento = '$usuario' 
    and  clave = '$clave'  and tipo_usuario = '$rol' " ;
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion , $consulta);
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    
    //-----------verificar los roles y las interfazes---------------
    // $datos será falso si el usuario no existe
    // o arreglo asociativo si el usuario fue encontrado
    if($datos){
        // Los datos son correctos, ahora sí se pueden crear las variables de sesión
        $_SESSION["user"] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION["rol"] = $rol;

        if($rol == 1){
            header("location:interfaz_superadmin.php");
        } elseif($rol == 2){
            header("location:interfaz_admin.php");
        } elseif($rol == 3){
            header("location:interfaz_operario.php");
        } else {
            // Limpiar variables de sesión
            $_SESSION["user"] = '';
            $_SESSION["rol"] = 0;
            echo "No existe su rol ";
        }
    } else {
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Datos incorrectos");
        window.location.href="login.php";   
        </script>';
    }
    ?>
```

El código siguiente es para validar el usuario y el rol en la interfaz del superadministrador , el archivo se llama interfaz_superadmin.php

```
    <?php
session_start(); // Esta debe ser siempre la primera instrucción
include "../includes/conexion.php";

// Verificación de usuario y rol
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) // No existe la variable de usuario
|| $_SESION['usuario'] == ''    // o está vacía
|| !isset($_SESSION['rol'])     // No existe la variable de rol
|| $_SESSION['rol'] != 1) {     // o no es 1 (superadmin)
    // Redirigir
    header('Location: login.php');
    // Finalizar ejecución del script, no debes omitir este paso
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
//AQUI MUESTRO LA INTERFAZ DEL USUARIO
```

Y el código siguiente esta en el archivo **registrar_venta.php que es donde quiero implementar mi botón volver hacia la interfaz correspondiente**

```
 <?php
session_start(); // Esta debe ser siempre la primera instrucción

include "../includes/conexion.php";

$consulta_cliente = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT documento , concat(nombres,' ',apellidos) as 'nombre' FROM tbl_cliente");
$consulta_f_pago = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codigo , nombre FROM tblformapago");
$consulta_producto = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codigo , nombre FROM tblproductoterminado");
$consulta_categoria = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codigo , nombre FROM tblcategoria ");
?>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <link  rel="icon" href="../img/logo_prov_pestaña.png"  />
    <title>Salidas | ventas </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/estilos/compra.css">
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="../factura/funcion.js"></script> -->


</head>

<body>


    <header class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start  mb-3 x">
            <?php
            $url = '../ingreso/interfaz_operario.php';
            switch($_SESSION['rol']) {
                case 1:
                    $url = '../ingreso/interfaz_superadmin.php';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $url = '../ingreso/interfaz_admin.php';
                    break;
            }
            // Mostrar botón
            echo "<a href=\"$url\" class='btn btn-light'>Volver</a>";
            ?>

    </header>
```

Comment: No logro entender tu pregunta. ¿Dónde está el problema exactamente? ¿Dónde tienes el botón? ¿Qué ocurre con este código: da error, qué error; funciona mal, qué hace mal? Etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya la corregí

Comment: Empieza corrigiendo los mensajes que te presenta. En la línea `7`usas una ¿constante? llamada `documento`, quizá sea una variable `$documento` que existe en el archivo del `include`. Luego, te dice que la variable `$rol` no existe. Debes corregir eso.

Comment: Como bien dice @Triby, ahora no estás leyendo ningún resultado, debes usar uno de los métodos `fetch`. Por otra parte, no veo que apliques ningún filtro en el `SELECT` ... te está trayendo todas las filas, ¿cómo decides el usuario que está solicitando esa consulta?

Comment: @A.Cedano No lo sé

Comment: ¿Acaso no estás implementando un sistema de login o parecido en el que cada usuario ingresa con su nombre de usuario / contraseña? En esa etapa podrías también verificar su rol, una vez haya hecho el login correctamente, y mostrar la interfaz que corresponda, ¿no?

Comment: Si, ese código existe. Tengo esta consulta ````$consulta = " SELECT * FROM tblusuario WHERE documento = '$usuario' and  clave = '$clave'  and tipo_usuario = '$rol' " ;
```` pero no se donde implementarla en el código , ni como traer los valores de las variables ya que en el login se traen por metodo post

Comment: Quizá tu problema más que nada es de **organizar bien el código**. La interfaz según el rol debería crearse/mostrarse/decidirse cuando el usuario ingresa al sistema, o sea, cuando se ejecuta esta consulta: `$consulta = " SELECT * FROM tblusuario WHERE documento = '$usuario' and  clave = '$clave'  and tipo_usuario = '$rol' " ;` Ahí tienes la información necesaria para saber: 1. Si le está permitido a ese usuario entrar o no (si no le está permitido entrar, se mostrará una interfaz o mensaje de No permitido); 2. Verificar el rol y en base a él presentar la interfaz correspondiente.

Comment: @Triby Tienes razón probe aquel código, con la diferencia de que allá se traen los datos ````$_POST```` pero yo los traigo por medio de un query, y al probarlo  sale ````Hay datos que no se llenaron, no se debe procesar```` Es decir las variables vienen vacias , Editaré la pregunta

Comment: @Karol, edita nuevamente la pregunta para agregar cómo haces el login, ahí es donde debes definir las variables de sesión para identificar el usuario que está en la página y, de hecho, te evitarías tener que hacer la consulta en este caso.

Comment: @Triby ya ,  porfavor revisala cuando puedas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta que te había sugerido en comentarios era para aplicar cuando el usuario inicia sesión y la lógica es muy simple:

1. Inicializar sesión (`session_start`) e incluir archivo de conexión
2. Limpiar variables de sesión, o eliminarlas, ambas opciones sirven
3. Tomar y limpiar datos de formulario desde $_POST
4. Ejecutar consulta
5. Crear variables de sesión solo si los datos son correctos

`validar_login.php` debería quedar así:

```
<?php
        session_start(); // Esta debe ser siempre la primera instrucción
        include ("../includes/conexion.php");

        // Limpiar variables de sesión
        $_SESSION["user"] = '';
        $_SESSION["rol"] = 0;

        //funcion de seguridad
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["documento"]) ;
        //funcon md5 contraseña encriptada
        $clave = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["clave"]) ;
        // También se debe escapar este dato
        $rol = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["rol"]);

        
        $consulta = " SELECT * FROM tblusuario WHERE documento = '$usuario' and  clave = '$clave'  and tipo_usuario = '$rol' " ;
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion , $consulta);
        $datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        
        //-----------verificar los roles y las interfazes---------------
        // $datos será falso si el usuario no existe
        // o arreglo asociativo si el usuario fue encontrado
        if($datos){
            // Los datos son correctos, ahora sí se pueden crear las variables de sesión
            $_SESSION["user"] = $usuario;
            $_SESSION["rol"] = $rol;

            if($rol == 1){
                header("location:interfaz_superadmin.php");
            } elseif($rol == 2){
                header("location:interfaz_admin.php");
            } elseif($rol == 3){
                header("location:interfaz_operario.php");
            } elseif($rol == 4){
                header("location:interfaz_operario.php");
            } elseif($rol == 5){
                header("location:interfaz_operario.php");
            } else {
                // Limpiar variables de sesión
                $_SESSION["user"] = '';
                $_SESSION["rol"] = 0;
                echo "No existe su rol ";
            }
        } else {
            echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Datos incorrectos");
            window.location.href="login.php";   
            </script>';
        }
```

En el resto de scripts ya puedes validar usuario en otras secciones de tu sitio:

1. Inicializar sesión (`session_start`) e incluir archivo de conexión
2. Verificar que existen usuario y rol en sesión
3. Validar que el rol es el adecuado para la sección del sitio
4. Redirigir a `login.php` si el usuario o rol no corresponden
5. Mostrar contenido

Por ejemplo, en `interfaz_superadmin.php` el rol debe ser 1:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Esta debe ser siempre la primera instrucción
include "../includes/conexion.php";

// Verificación de usuario y rol
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) // No existe la variable de usuario
|| $_SESION['usuario'] == ''    // o está vacía
|| !isset($_SESSION['rol'])     // No existe la variable de rol
|| $_SESSION['rol'] != 1) {     // o no es 1 (superadmin)
    // Redirigir
    header('Location: login.php');
    // Finalizar ejecución del script, no debes omitir este paso
    exit;
}
// Aquí muestras el contenido para el Superadmin
```

En `interfaz_operario.php` el rol debe ser 3:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Esta debe ser siempre la primera instrucción
include "../includes/conexion.php";

// Verificación de usuario y rol
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) // No existe la variable de usuario
|| $_SESION['usuario'] == ''    // o está vacía
|| !isset($_SESSION['rol'])     // No existe la variable de rol
|| $_SESSION['rol'] != 3) {     // o no es 3 (operario)
    // Redirigir
    header('Location: login.php');
    // Finalizar ejecución del script, no debes omitir este paso
    exit;
}
// Aquí muestras el contenido para el Operario
```

Ahora, para crear el botón puedes usar un switch:

```
// Esto después de haber validado sesión y rol
$url = 'interfaz_operario.php';
switch($_SESSION['rol']) {
    case 1:
        $url = 'interfaz_superadmin.php';
        break;
    case 2:
        $url = 'interfaz_admin.php';
        break;
}
// Mostrar botón
echo "<a href=\"$url\">Volver</a>";
```

Comment: Gracias, intenté aplicar el código a mi problema, pero no lo logré  aún no he entendido bien donde poner el botón para que me funcione, lo intenté hacer en **interfaz.php** un diferente   , luego enlazar el archivo  en **<a></a>** pero no me funciona  . Tampoco entiendo porque hay codigo de sesiones en la interfaz_superadmin.php cuando lo uso asi, no me deja entrar asi entre con los datos correctos , edité la pregunta espero puedas ayudarme porfavor

Comment: Cuando agregó el codigo de las sesiones a ````interfaz_superamin.php```` o otra interfaz, no me deja ingresar incluso si tiene los datos correctos del login

Comment: Inmediatamente después de `session_start();` agrega `var_dump($_SESSION); die();` y dime lo que aparece.

Comment: array(2) { ["user"]=> string(10) "1005091870" ["rol"]=> string(1) "3" }, edité la pregunta de todas maneras por si depronto puse algo donde no va

Comment: pero es que es muy raro porque cuando implemento el codigo en ````interfaz_operario.php```` con el rol 3 , no me deja y de todas formas, si cambio el 3 por el 1 no puedo entrar a ninguna interfaz

Comment: Agregué el ejemplo para la interfaz de operario, solo se modifica el `if`

Comment: Asi lo tengo pero pasa lo que te digo